# Convergence of a series with numbers without a digit 5?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

I’m trying to find out the convergence \ divergence of two series:

An:

= 0, when n = number with digit "5" in decimal notation

= 1/n, when n = number without digit "5"

Bn on the contrary:

= 0, when n = number without digit "5"

= 1/n, when n = number with digit "5"

I proved only that their sum converges according to the integral Cauchy-Maclaurin criterion (this is the last topic before this task and I don't know, how to approach the task.

Comment: $\sum_nA_n$ is just the [Kempner Series](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/KempnerSeries.html) $K_5$ and $\sum_nB_n=\sum_n\frac1n-\sum_nA_n$ is hence divergent.

Comment: Thank you very mach!